# Trouble joining list of unicode strings and passing them to html via flask flash()

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to join a list of unicode values and pass them to the web page as a flashed message (flask) and am experiencing an error. Relevant Code:

```
duplicate_values = [u'blitz media\xe2\u20ac\xa8', u'mars technologies ltd.'']
```

The duplicate values are originally pulled from a csv file via unicodecsv module:

```
import unicodecsv as csv

with open(file_name, 'rb') as raw_file:
    csv_read = csv.reader(raw_file, encoding='utf-8')
    data = [row[0] for row in csv_read]
```

After analyzing the 'data' list and parsing out the duplicate values, I want to join them and flash them to the user when the next page loads:

```
msg = "Duplicates detected in import file: {}".format(','.join(x.encode('utf-8') for x in duplicate_values))
    flash(msg)
```

The HTML document contains:

```
{% with msgs = get_flashed_messages() %}
{% if msgs %}
{%- for msg in msgs %}
<div class="alert alert-danger">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
        {{ msg }}
</div>
{% endfor -%}
{% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

The error:

```
> File "/Users/**/Desktop/In Progress/import-validation/templates/upload.html", line 18, in block "body"
{{ msg }}
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 501: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've read the flask [unicode documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/unicode/) and the [external reference](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) mentioned but am still pretty new to handling special characters properly. Do I need to be encoding the values differently before passing them to the flash() function? Or maybe I'm not storing them as proper unicode when they are initially pulled into memory? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is the goal to exclude the special characters or get them to render properly?

Comment: How about pass a `msg` of unicode type to the Jinja? From the exception message, Jinja is try to encode your str to unicode.

Comment: @dizzyfn The goal is to have the special characters render properly.

Comment: @stamaimer I changed it to: `msg = u"Duplicates detected in import file: {}".format(','.join(duplicate_values))` This now renders properly on the page. If you want to submit it as an answer I'm happy to mark it accepted. Thanks a lot